# Node.js async with multiple models to db

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I know there's library like async.js but now I'm building something small (ardiunio) so I try not to complicated thing.

I have one confusion with below code. This

```
..
    router.post('/do_something', function(req, res) {

      Account.updateStatus(req.body.username, function(err,result){
        //res.json(result); comment it out to avoid error
      });

      Photo.getApprovedPhotos(req.body.username,function(err,result){
        res.json(result);
      });

    });
```

Account and Photo is the model with query, the both return their callback. My confusion is how should I structure the code. If I nested one within another that's not async anymore.

Comment: What is Account & Photo? Do those functions have alternatives that return promises? Promises make this sort of thing easy to structure.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to add async.js, but honestly *some* kind of flow control library (that, or using Promises) will make this do what you want it to.  And I don't think there's a good reason to avoid it, even if you're on arduino.